# Merging two large tables physically in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a requirement to merge two large tables with redundant data.

Table A and Table B both have more than a billion records, most of the data including columns are redundant except 5 additional columns in Table B.

I would like to merge them physically and delete table B by comparing the data between both table and load the data that doesn't exist in Table A but exist in Table B to Table A.

Ultimate goal is to get rid of Table B and load all data and columns to Table A and then partition table A.

Did anyone had experience doing this? How can I compare the data between two large tables? Can we use Informatica or any native SQL tools? Is it a good approach to merge the tables and partition Table A or first partition Table A and them merge the tables?

Please let me know if you need any details.

Comment: "Please let me know if you need any details." - table details, at least key columns and indexes. Also some summary of data patterns such as how many rows are likely to be in just A / just B / both?

Comment: David, Thanks for the response...will send the details but my question is in general....on how would you compare data between two tables when they are large....and is it a good approach to merge and partition or partition Table A first and then merge the data ?

Comment: Provide the table DDL even if you need to obfuscate the column names as this may provide useful information on ways to perform the comparisons.  Also, when comparing rows between the tables are there any special conditions within the data to be aware of?  Finally, do you need to compare all data within the columns or is a key comparison sufficient?

Comment: Also, what other constraints might you have? I assume you can't simply set up a query or two to make these changes and let them run for as long as it might take, as that could make both tables less responsive than usual for days. Can you do this incrementally - that is to say, resolve say 10000 rows in table B a night, updating/inserting into table A as needed, then removing those rows from table B? Is data in table B still changing, or is it static at this point?

Comment: Check this links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001980/update-or-merge-of-very-big-tables-in-sql-server   &   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750410/merge-2-tables-in-sql-and-save-into-1-new-table

Comment: Thanks everyone. Here's the link with table, index and key information : https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiAvWVQ84i-Ain-f_1pn4TUSiEtV

Comment: RDFozz, Yes, we will compare and load incrementally, probably based on datetime column. There are no constraints on these tables. Yes, data in both table changes. But the goal is compare, find the rows or data that doesnt exist in tableA but exist in TableB and load it to table A. We are not planning to delete rows in TableB, just drop it once the comparison and load is complete.

Answer (score -1):

going to take a while on 3 billion records but this is a query

```
select tableB.* 
from tableB 
left join tableA 
on tableA.ID = tableB.ID 
where tableA.ID is null
```